# Append Hash to Array

Tags: ruby

I have a little problem with this exercise, can you help me? I tried to edit a script, but for each time that I create new instance the last element overwrites the Others (i.e. )

The class must provide a functionality for the combination of consequent blocks: i.e. it must be able to inherit from the previous block the instructions that have not been explicitly deﬁned for the current block.

```
blocks = [] 

blocks << Block.new({ X:0, Y:100, Z:20}) # p blocks:({ X:0, Y:100, Z:20}) 

blocks << Block.new({X:100}, blocks[-1]) #p blocks:({ X:100, Y:100, Z:20},{ X:100, Y:100, Z:20})

blocks << Block.new({Y:0}, blocks[-1]) #p blocks:({ X:100, Y:0, Z:20},{ X:100, Y:0, Z:20},{ X:100, Y:0, Z:20})
```

My code with problems is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

    class Block


      $instance_2 = true
      $instance_3 = true


      attr_reader :out


      def initialize(out, previous = nil )

        @out = update(out, previous)
      end # end initialize


      def update(actual, previous)
        puts "IN UPDATE: box is: #{previous}"
        box = previous
        if box != nil      
          puts "IF: changing is: #{actual}"
          actual.each do |key, value|
            box[key] = value               
          end  
           box  
        else
          puts "ELSE"
             actual   
        end # end if 
      end # end update

      def inspect
        @out
      end



    end # end Block

    blocks = []
    puts "\n#----------------------1 INSTANCE----------------------#" 
    blocks << Block.new({G: "00", X: 100, Y:100, Z: 100})
    puts "\n#----------------------blocks element----------------------#" 
    p blocks
    puts "last block is: #{blocks[-1].out}"

    puts "\n#----------------------2 INSTANCE----------------------#"  if $instance_2
    blocks << Block.new({G: "01"}, blocks[-1].out) if $instance_2 
    puts "\n#----------------------blocks element----------------------#"if $instance_2 
    p blocks if $instance_2
    puts "last block is: #{blocks[-1].out}"


    puts "\n#----------------------3 INSTANCE----------------------#" if $instance_3
    blocks << Block.new({G: "02"}, blocks[-1].out) if $instance_3 
    puts "\n#----------------------blocks element----------------------#" if $instance_3
    p blocks if $instance_3
    puts "last block is: #{blocks[-1].out}"

    puts "\n#----------------------4 INSTANCE----------------------#" if $instance_3
    blocks << Block.new({G: "03"}, blocks[-1].out) if $instance_3 
    puts "\n#----------------------blocks element----------------------#" if $instance_3
    p blocks if $instance_3
    puts "last block is: #{blocks[-1].out}"
```

Comment: Mh... It seems that someone is making some exercise for Manufacturing Automation, am I right? For who is reading, the Block class is a G-code statement.

Comment: Hi Matteo, is a exercise for a course of 3d printer, where we have to implement the gcode.
Have you any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: Can you please explain better which is the problem with your code and what have you tried? it is not clear in your question.

Comment: i edited the question, this is my trial, but for each instance that i create the last value of hash ovewrite all the previous element, try it if you have a time.
Thank you very much friend

Comment: Ciao Luca, I have added to my answer a sectionthat explains which is the issue with your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not exactly clear, but if I understand it correctly it is possible to provide a class that may or not accept a previous Block. What do you think of something like that?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Block < Hash

  def initialize(h, b=nil)
    [:x, :y, :z].each do |s|
      # We start by trying to assign the coordinate that is in the 
      # input hash
      if h[s]
        self[s] = h[s]
      else
      # If the coordinate is not in h, we check for it in b, but we have to
      # remember that if the block that we are providing in b does not have
      # the method :[] or the coordinate is nil we may raise an exception
        begin
          self[s] = b[s]
          raise if not self[s]
        rescue
          raise(Exception, "Cannot initialize block.")   
        end  
      end
    end 
  end

  def inspect
    "block:(x: #{self[:x]}, y: #{self[:y]}, z: #{self[:z]}"
  end
end

# Let's try it!
blocks = [] 
blocks << Block.new({ x:0, y:100, z:20}) 
puts blocks
puts
blocks << Block.new({x:100}, blocks[-1]) 
puts blocks
puts
blocks << Block.new({y:0}, blocks[-1])
puts blocks
puts
```

### With respect to your code

Let's consider only the update method:

```
def update(actual, previous)
    puts "IN UPDATE: box is: #{previous}"
    box = previous                 # ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! WHOOPS!
    if box != nil      
      puts "IF: changing is: #{actual}"
      actual.each do |key, value|
        box[key] = value               
      end  
       box  
    else
      puts "ELSE"
         actual   
    end # end if 
  end # end update
```

the "whoops" line is what is creating you the issue. With that line 
you are giving the reference to `previous` (your object variable actually contains a reference) to the `box` variable. What you are actually doing, when you perform some action on `box`, is modifying what is pointed by both variable.

You can test what I'm saying immediately. Try to modify that line in this way:

```
box = previous.clone if previous
```

(`nil` does not have a method `#clone` that the rationale behind the `if`). If you run it again you will get a list of blocks that have not being modified. This is not an efficient code tough, and you should really rethink the `update` method code.

Comment: wow, it works exactly as i want. i made a lot of error in my code :( 
Thank you very much for you time friend

Comment: It is a good thing that you are trying and you are understanding which are the mistakes you made. In this context it is a good way to learn. Keep trying.